# What is the best way to store site configuration/option in database using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there some library available to store site configurations fields data in database, like in WordPress https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/
and in Drupal https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7.x

Or is there any good approach to store site variables? and allow admin to modify also. I have been working in CMS just checking out better approaches in Codeigniter

Comment: From the related questions list, [this seems like a pretty good answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870189/3585500)

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to application > config > database file and edit database config.
    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'exampl_database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```